# External table is not loading properly

Tags: unix, hive

I have a hive query that loads data into an external table. Are there any possibilities that the data may not be loaded into table!!!

When i ran the query manually, the table is loaded with data. But when it is running in automation script, some times data is not getting populated into the table.I have all the access to the paths and i'm using MAPR distribution

Please help me to understand this scenario.

Here is my code snippet,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS A
(
.
.
.
.
.
.
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'a/b/c/d/A'

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE <DB_NAME>.A
SELECT
DISTINCT
.
.
.
.
.
.
FROM <DB_NAME>.B;

if [ -s 'a/b/c/d/A' ]; then
    echo "Data found"
else
    echo "No data found"
fi
```

When ran the query manually, i'm able to see single record but when through UNIX automation, it is printing **No data found**. I mean data was not loading into table

Comment: share your table data set script

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ -s 'a/b/c/d/A' ]; then
    echo "Data found"
else
    echo "No data found"
fi
```

It should not work because your data is located on hdfs. 
Use the hdfs test command instead. Below an example:

```
`hdfs dfs -test -e /a/b/c/d/A`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
else
    echo "No data found"
fi
```

Comment: Its an external table and path is not warehouse path... We are using MAPR distribution

Comment: I can agree with your suggestion.. here my scenario is data also not populating into the table, But manually running the query loading the data into table

Comment: MAPR, ok (it was not stated in the initial problem). You should check the values returned by hive when executing your queries. Check that [link](https://www.mapr.com/blog/quick-tips-using-hive-shell-inside-scripts#.VTYZB5NJ6gl) to set this up.